# oracle sql related to multi database

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT t.FIRST_NAME,
       t.LAST_NAME,
       t.GENDER,
       t.DOB,
       subj.NAME sub_name,
       coll.NAME college_name,
       univ.NAME university_name,
       dom.name domain,
       countr.NAME country_name
  FROM TEACHER_TB t,
       SUBJECT_TB subj,
       COLLG_TCHR_TB ct,
       COLLEGE_TB coll,
       UNIVERSITY_TB univ,
       DOMAIN_TB dom,
       COUNTRY_TB countr
 WHERE     t.SUBJECT_ID = subj.SUBJECT_ID
       AND ct.TEACHER_ID = t.TEACHER_ID
       AND coll.COLLEGE_ID = ct.COLLEGE_ID
       AND coll.UNIVERSITY_ID = univ.UNIVERSITY_ID
       AND dom.DOMAIN_ID = coll.DOMAIN_ID
       AND countr.COUNTRY_ID = univ.COUNTRY_ID
```

This query is giving me my data but in that 10 rows i need to pick only those names(name r tecaher name) who r teaching in more than 1 college.so need some help here how to implement for fectchng those 2 names.

Comment: Please have a look at [mcve] to improve this question

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

```
t.FIRST_NAME,
       t.LAST_NAME,
       t.GENDER,
       t.DOB,
       subj.NAME sub_name,
       coll.NAME college_name,
       univ.NAME university_name,
       dom.name domain,
       countr.NAME country_name
TEACHER_TB t,
       SUBJECT_TB subj,
       COLLG_TCHR_TB ct,
       COLLEGE_TB coll,
       UNIVERSITY_TB univ,
       DOMAIN_TB dom,
       COUNTRY_TB countr    
where 
t.SUBJECT_ID = subj.SUBJECT_ID
       AND ct.TEACHER_ID = t.TEACHER_ID
       AND coll.COLLEGE_ID = ct.COLLEGE_ID
       AND coll.UNIVERSITY_ID = univ.UNIVERSITY_ID
       AND dom.DOMAIN_ID = coll.DOMAIN_ID
       AND countr.COUNTRY_ID = univ.COUNTRY_ID

 and t.teacher_id in(    
           SELECT t.TEACHER_ID         
           FROM TEACHER_TB t,       
           COLLG_TCHR_TB ct,
           COLLEGE_TB coll           
           WHERE     
           ct.TEACHER_ID = t.TEACHER_ID
           AND coll.COLLEGE_ID = ct.COLLEGE_ID           
           group by t.TEACHER_ID having count(coll.college_id)>1
           )
```

Comment: I can convert this select to JOIN syntax if you want. This is old syntax.

Comment: İ used group by and having to find teacher_ids working in two or more colleges.